# How to print first N bytes of a txt file?

Tags: r

I wrote a script, which calculates my txt file's byte size:

```
byte.counter <- nchar(mytxtfile, type = "bytes")
```

The size of my txt is around 28894 bytes and I would like to print it out in N-byte chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following function is a first step. It breaks the input text into character vectors of `length.segm` characters each. Then all what is needed is to print them.

```
char.segments <- function(x, segm.length){
  byte.counter <- nchar(x, type = 'bytes')
  f <- c(1, rep(0, segm.length - 1))
  f <- cumsum(rep(f, length.out = byte.counter))
  s <- split(unlist(strsplit(x,'')), f)
  unname(sapply(s, paste, collapse = ''))
}

mytxtfile <- paste(rep(letters, 10), collapse = '')
char.segments(mytxtfile, 26)
# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
# [4] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
# [7] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#[10] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```